# Consume OData service from java

Tags: java, odata

I'm developing a mobile application. For database communication I want to use my existing way: WCF Data Service (which is an OData service).

I'm not often programming with java, but I thought this will not be a problem. Failed.

My first try was the odata4j library. All the time I got NullPointerExceptions (I tried really small things like `getEntities`. It took about one hour to recognize that the documentation is outdated and `ODataConsumer.create(..)` does not longer exist and you need to use `ODataJerseyConsumer`).

Then I tried to use a class I found in the internet: `RestClient` which is available [here](http://lukencode.com/2010/04/27/calling-web-services-in-android-using-httpclient/). I did some modification and in the end it was working, but it does not support odata functionallity (queries like $filter, $oderby, ...) and for each request I need a new instance.. so I'm not happy with it.

Then I tried my own implementation with `HttpClient` and `JSONObject` classes. It is a lot of code to do things like I want to and it is very uncomfortable.

So the question is: Is there another library you can recommend that I missed? Do you have any hints how to implement my own "OData Consumer library" or do you want me to invest more time into odata4j?

Comment: Are you developing for iPhone or Android?

Comment: In this case for android, but iOS will follow. The first approach was using phoneGap but the performance was very bad, so I implement my app on each specific platform again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found myself in a very similar situation just a month ago.

I recommend that you go back to OData4j for Android development. When you run into issues or get confused, post to the [OData4j forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/odata4j-discuss). John Spurlock, the create of OData4j, personally responds to almost all of the posts there. When I was having issues (I created a producer, not a consumer), he was VERY patient and prompt in his responses.

OData4j doesn't have the nearly as many tutorials as it should. So take good notes of the steps you go through and then share your expertise afterwards!!

As for iOS development with OData, the best out there is [OData4ObjC](https://github.com/OData/odata4objc). Unfortunately, the current version was abandoned about a year ago and therefore doesn't support iOS 6. I've updated the code and samples to work. it can be found [here](https://github.com/ElizabethDuncan/OData4ObjC).

Good luck! And let me know how it goes! I'm considering making an Android app that integrates OData also. :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. At the moment I wrote my own small class which does the networking stuff. But basically it's just the `RestClient` class I've posted in my question. I think I will invest some more hours into OData4j. A very bad point is that `OData4ObjC` was abandoned. I really wonder about that, because I thought OData serices are the non-plus-ultra for doing network stuff in apps. ^^